# Получение цвета в формате RGB по положению мыши в приложении

Tags: c++, windows

Решил сделать настройку цвета. Создал палитру:

```
void  render_ColorPolet(float x, float y, float w, float h, IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice)
{
    struct D3DVERTEX
    {
        float x, y, w, h;
        DWORD color;
    };

    D3DVERTEX   vertices[] =
    {
        { x, y, w, h, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 255, 0) },
        { x + w, y, w, h, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 255, 0, 0) },
        { x, y + h, w, h, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 0, 255) },
        { x + w, y + h, w, h, D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255, 0, 255, 0) }
    };

    pDevice->SetTexture(0, NULL);
    pDevice->SetPixelShader(0);
    pDevice->SetFVF(D3DFVF_XYZRHW | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE);
    pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, true);
    pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);
    pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, FALSE);
    pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);

    pDevice->DrawPrimitiveUP(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 2, vertices, sizeof(D3DVERTEX));
}
```

Получил положение курсора:

```
POINT mpos;
GetCursorPos(&mpos);
ScreenToClient(GetForegroundWindow(), &mpos);
int Os_x = mpos.x;
int Os_y = mpos.y;
```

Теперь нужно получить по этим координатам цвет, записывая например в RGB. Я решил определить макрос:

```
#define COLOR_A_TEST(r,g,b) D3DCOLOR_ARGB(255,r,g,b)
```

Осталось всего ничего, определить цвет. И тут я встрял, по многим форумам пролазил, говорят нужно юзать `GetPixel`. Не могу понять как, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Предлагаю вам убрать из вопроса упоминание о DirectX чтобы не вводить будущих читателей в заблуждение, так как вопрос совершенно DirectX не касается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так это можно сделать:

```
 COLOREF GetWindowPixel(HWND window, int x, int y)
 {
     auto window_dc = GetDC(window);             // получаем контекст устройства
     if(window_dc)
     {
         auto pixel = GetPixel(window_dc, x, y); // получаем цвет
         ReleaseDC(window_dc);                   // освобождаем контекст
         return pixel;
     }
     return CLR_INVALID;
 }
```

Обратите внимание, что функции [GetDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx) можно передать хэндл окна равный `NULL` и тогда вы получите контекст экрана и соответвенно пиксель будет в координатах экрана. То есть передавая `NULL` можно получать цвета пикселей в глобальных координатах и вне своего окна. Таким образом, вы можете использовать функцию `GetWindowPixel` так:

```
POINT mpos = {0};
GetCursorPos(&mpos);
// ScreenToClient(GetForegroundWindow(), &mpos);
// int Os_x = mpos.x;
// int Os_y = mpos.y;
auto color = GetWindowPixel(NULL, mpos.x, mpos.y);
```

Comment: А что делать есле красный определяеться как синий ?

Comment: @ЕгорГлухов Проверить что вы правильно получате цветовые компоненты. У [COLOREF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449(v=vs.85).aspx) они такие `0x00bbggrr` или задать новый вопрос на эту тему.